# Ошибка Invalid configuration request for gameId unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, ads

Всем доброго времени суток.
При инициализации unity ads появляется ошибка: `Invalid configuration request for gameId unity: id игры`. Подождал 12 часов, ничего не изменилось. Пробовал сделать в другом приложении в более старой версии - результат тот же. VPN работал. Версии пробовал 4.4.1 и 3.7.5 
AdsInizializer.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdsInitializer : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsInitializationListener
{

[SerializeField] string androidGameID = "xxxxxxx";
[SerializeField] string iOSGameID = "xxxxxxx";
[SerializeField] bool testMode = true;
private string gameID;

void Awake()
{
    InitializeAds();
}
public void InitializeAds()
{
    gameID = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) ? iOSGameID : androidGameID;
    Advertisement.Initialize(gameID, testMode, this);
}

public void OnInitializationComplete()
{
    Debug.Log("Unity Ads initialization complete.");
}

public void OnInitializationFailed(UnityAdsInitializationError error, string message)
{
    Debug.Log($"Unity Ads Initialization Failed: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
}
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста убрать эту ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Надо проверить, что в Build settings выбрана платформа Android или IOS.
2. Unity ads работает в России, но не работает на оккупированных территориях Украины(ДНР, ЛНР, Крым и др.)